# accidentally deleted app delegate.h and .m and cannot restore them

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally removed app `delegate.m` and `.h` file from the folder of the app.

Then in xcode I could see the name (`Appdelegate.h and .m`) but with no content.

I found the files in the trash and I dragged and dropped them in the xcode and now I see doubles of both files.

If i try to run my project I keep getting this error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppDelegate._window in:
```

If I remove the one of the two duplicates, both are being deleted.

Comment: Remove both, then add again ?

Comment: did it, but not worked. Thats why I posted here..

Comment: Perhaps you can fix it by editing the .pbxproj manually. Find the guid for the files, then look to see if it is repeated twice somewhere. (Take a backup - the file format is a bit scary and not meant to be hand-edited -- even better, use a version control system -- it would have saved you by now if you had one ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `delegate.m` is only listed once within the Compile-Sources.

To get that done; tap on your project on the left top within the project navigator, tap on the target, select `Build Phases`, expand `Compile Source` and now check if `delegate.m` is in there only once.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Till's answer, I also suggest you remove your project's DerivedData folder to rebuild your project from scratch (performing a "Clean" in the "Product" menu may be sufficient, or alt-clic on the "Clean" menu item to choose "Clean Build Folder…" is a bit better, but sometimes it is not enough)

To remove all your intermediate files and force Xcode to rebuild your project from scratch, avoiding it to use old built files, do the following:

- Open the Organizer (menu "Window")
- Go to the "Projects" tab, then select your project on the left
- Click on the "Delete" button next to the "Derived Data" line
- Rebuild your project